# e-paper "im away" screen connecting with custom ios app

Tags: ios, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

i managed to connect a raspberry pi zero to an e-paper screen and run a demo from this tutorial:
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7.5inch_e-Paper_HAT_(B)_Manual#Python

now i want to make this e-paper screen into a screen that i can turn on with any text/images i input with a custom ios app, but i have no idea what im doing, so any ideas are welcome

i tried looking up any free app creator that allows for connection with arduino/raspberry pi, but i couldnt find it.

Comment: This is too open-ended. There a multiple ways to communicate between a phone and a raspberry pi (bluetooth, wifi). You'll certainly need programming experience to make an application on both the phone and pi to facilitate communication and display of the image. An app building tool won't be able to pull it off.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.